# ListView SelectedItem not updating from View Model using MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm-light, selecteditem

I am using MVVM light to bind a ListView to an ItemSource on my ViewModel.  When a change is made to the property on the ViewModel the SelectedItem does not update in the View.

XAML:

`<ListView Grid.Row="1"
          SelectionMode="Single" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding filteredAppListItemSource}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding selectedApp, Mode=TwoWay}">`

ViewModel:

`public Model.V_PWT_APP_ALL selectedApp
            {
            get { return this._selectedApp; }
            set { 
                this._selectedApp = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => selectedApp);
                }
            }`

Selecting an Item from the View updates the ViewModel and all controls that derive their data from SelectedItem are updated.  The TwoWay binding does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the problem was with the SelectedItem Binding.  I found that I wasn't selecting an item correctly.  I switch to using SelectedIndex and finding the correct index and the binding works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to stay with the INotified property changed interface you should set up the code as in the following documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184414(v=vs.110).aspx .

As it does not seem like you are changing properties, but rather items and notifying the ItemsSource, a better route would be to implement an IObserver/IObservable interface. This is a little more simple and it keeps updating tidy and  manageable inside of the models own class. Here is a possible code example:

```
public class App: IObservable<App>     //where the model class is the IObserver.

{

private App app;
internal App
List<IObserver<App>> Observers = new List<IObserver<App>>();

{

     get:
            {

                 return app;
            }

     set:

            {
                 app = value;
                 try
                 {
                      foreach (var observer in Observers) observer.OnNext(value);
                      foreach (var observer in Observers) observer.OnCompleted();
                 }
                 catch(Exception ex)
                 {
                      foreach (var observer in Observers) observer.OnError(ex);
                      throw;
                 }
            }
}
```

For the viewModel:

```
public Model.V_PWT_APP_ALL selectedApp: IOberver<App>
{
     List<Control> ControlsToBeUpdated = new List<Control>() //Each control that needs updated should implement and interface that has an .Update(type T) method where T is whatever value needs updated.
     public void OnCompleted()
     {
          //...notify taskBar, etc. 
     }

     public void OnError(Exception error)
     {
         //handle exception, update log, etc.
     }

     public void OnNext(object value)
     {
         foreach (var control in ControlsToBeUpdated) control.Update(value);
     }
}
```

This might seem tedious at first, but it has helped me minimize and manage updates and bugs in ItemsSource quite nicely. Finally, I have found controlling the scrollView rather tedious when working with the ListView ItemsSource, and have had better luck with simply using ListView.Items.Insert(...) method as when the ItemsSource is updated and a scrollview has been selected it has often thrown an OutOfRange exception. This can be difficult debugging in MVVM. However, this is another topic. I hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting approach.  However, the ItemsSource doesn't appear to be the problem here.  It is the SelectedItem that is the issue:

`SelectedItem="{Binding selectedApp, Mode=TwoWay}"`

I am updating selectedApp, and doing a RaisePropertyChanged, but the selected item does not change.

Comment: I believe you will need to add an even to handle the selection changed to your code. It seems you are binding to the app selected on loading, and not to the app clicked on in ListView. Instead of using the setter of Model.V_PWT_APP_ALL selectedApp, create a method to handle Selection changed in your C# code and place RaisePropertyChanged(() => selectedApp) in that method by using (sender as ListView).SelectedItem. Add the event to the SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged"/>

Comment: The XAML should be <ListView Grid.Row="1"
          SelectionMode="Single" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding filteredAppListItemSource}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding selectedApp, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged"/>

Comment: I already have a handler for a SelectionChanged Event

`                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding appListClick}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>`

This works when you use the UI and click (select) an item.  The binding from my View to the ViewModel works.  The issue is getting the View to select an item based off of a change in the ViewModel.

Comment: Thehe IObserver/IObservable pattern was created for push based commands. Your ViewModel needs to contain a list of ModelView's to push an update on change. The standard format is already incorporated into the interfaces provided by these Microsoft. On the setter you can simply call on the ViewModels .OnNext(object o) method to update the ModelView.  The NotifyPropertyChanged is not a good fit for going from ViewModel to ModelView, but can be made to work. IObserver/IObservable is better. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you.  I have a few more things to try now, I'll post back if I come to a solution.